# Fixed Receive buffer size between two process

Tags: c, linux, logic, ipc

I have a two process lets have process A and B, in which a process A should write into memory  with variable length(eg: 400 bytes at one time 1200 bytes at next time) through some IPC mechanism and Process B should read that with Fixed length(eg:1024 bytes every time). and both will do this continuously. 
So my question is through which IPC mechanism can I achieve this?
It can be socket,shared memory or socket etc.

Actually we are handling video packets within board. There are two process in which one will get data from encoder/camera and send it to another process. The another process will get the data and send it to decoder/LCD. Now our constraint is encoder will send packets in ***varying length*** but decoder will decode packets only if it is ***fixed length*** i.e 1024 packets every time. 
We tried unix datagram socket between two process but at receiving side how can I restrict/wait for the process to receive only 1024 bytes. 
Is there any **Flags available** to do the above in socket communication or pipe.

Kindly help me.
Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: You should come up with your own approach first; you seem to know common IPC techniques. Then we can talk about its scalability, flexibility, validity, etc.

Comment: Shared memory is certainly one option. An Unix domain stream socket will also work. A TCP/IP socket (via loopback interface if local to machine) will also work. A normal pipe will work. A named pipe will work, although one opener will block until the other end is also opened. Thus, no "which"; **many** work for this. Each one has their upsides and downsides, but they're difficult to compare without detailed information -- including the factors to weigh; portability, ease of maintenance, robustness, efficiency, bandwidth used, maximum/minimum latencies, and so on.

Comment: Personally, I'd start with an Unix domain stream socket, as that's most common and possibly easiest to use. However, I'd make sure I'd modularize it sufficiently, so that if I find it insufficient/undesirable for any reason, I could replace it with something else. (And that something else is typically shared memory. Which I wouldn't start with, due to complexity and marginality of benefits in the common cases.)

Comment: Keep in mind that access to concurrently used variables (shared memory) needs to be protected. So going for a socket definitely is the easier way.

Comment: thanks all for your valuable comments:)